# Other Excel 2013 users command buttons inop after I save

Tags: excel, vba

A few days ago the macro buttons on spreadsheets we created stopped working.
It acted like the buttons weren't even there.

After I searched for and deleted all *.exd files, the buttons once again worked for me.
All other users, though, can't start the macro after I save the file.

Simply - if there's a spreadsheet they're using, it works fine.
Once I open and save on exit, the buttons no longer work for anyone else.
They depress, but won't run the macro.

One thing I did notice on the sheet we use the most:
There are 2 buttons, CommandButton1 and CommandButton2.
If another user clicks on button 1 for instance, and I open the code, a new line is created called CommandButton3 (and 4).

I've tried renaming buttons,  etc. but this behavior continues and seems to skirt any of my feeble attempts.
Please help and thank you!

Comment: Please post the code which activates on CommandButton Click().